# How do I know python path on linux ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

In ubuntu linux if we want to set up python path we do something like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/etc ...
```

Now, how I would know what the current path I have?

Comment: `printenv PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: You question is not very clear, do you want to see the variable in the terminal or in python?  You've got both answers below, but you should make the question clearer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, I hope you don't really set `PYTHONPATH=/etc`, `/etc` is for configuration files, not python libraries.

You can see what an environment variable is set to by using `echo`, e.g.: `echo $PYTHONPATH`.  If the variable has not been set it will be blank.  You can also use `env` to get a list of all environment variables, and couple with `grep` to see if a particular one is set, e.g. `env | grep PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Ya it was bad example to use `/etc` .

Answer (score 37):

You can type **`which python`** on the ubuntu terminal and it will give the Python installed location path.

Answer (score 11):

use printenv command, it will print all the environment variables,
to only print PYTHONPATH use:
    printenv PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 3):

Command:

```
which python
```

gives path to python

as:

```
which python3
```

gives python3 path

Comment: This is not the PYTHONPATH environment variable as is referred to in the question